# Non-nullable instance field '_animationControllers' must be initialized

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using the mpin_animation plugin in flutter. I don't understand _MpinWidgetState, why it occures error. How to fix it?

error message below

Non-nullable instance field '_animationControllers' must be initialized. (Documentation)  Try adding an initializer expression, or add a field initializer in this constructor, or mark it 'late'.
Non-nullable instance field '_wiggleAnimation' must be initialized. (Documentation)

```
class _MPinWidgetState extends State<MPinWidget>
with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  List<MPinAnimationController> _animationControllers;
  AnimationController _wrongInputAnimationController;
  Animation<double> _wiggleAnimation;
  String mPin = '';

  _MPinWidgetState(MPinController controller) {
    controller?.addInput = addInput;
    controller?.delete = delete;
    controller?.notifyWrongInput = notifyWrongInput;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

initialise your controllers in your initState

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _wrongInputAnimationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(your duration here),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize the fields, for example:

```
List<MPinAnimationController> _animationControllers = [
   ...
];
```

You have to give it something like 'a default value'.

By adding 'late' you can initialze them later in your code, for example in initState:

```
late List<MPinAnimationController> _animationControllers;

...

@override
void initState()
{
   super.initState();
   _animationControllers = [...];
}
```